# IIS ignoring MVC mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-8

I'm trying to deploy to IIS 8.5 a ASP.NET MVC5 application but I'm able to see only static resources (images).

It seems like the mapping is not recognized (module System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule).

The only way I have for deploying is to copy and past files after publish the application in a local folder (no possibility to use Web Deploy).

Global.asax file seems be ok referring the cs

<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Xxxxxx.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>

Any help is appreciated to exit to this hell...

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to reset the IIS? Run `iisreset` in an elevated command prompt should do

Comment: The approach to copy/paste things can be quite problematic if you are less familiar with IIS configuration. Did you deploy the files to a virtual directory on IIS? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis

Comment: Does your ASP.NET MVC dynamic page fail to load with "Resource not found"?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! In the server features "ASP .Net 4.5" and ".Net Extensibility 4.5" under "Application Development Features" were not installed :(

The fact that my application uses .Net 4.6 framework (installed on the server) and the fact that the feature folder contains the word "Development" had deceived me...